# Visual Studio source control not puting Git repo in right place - how to fix?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, in Team Explorer, I have my default repository location set to C:\Users\Tim\Source\Repos. However, when I create a new project and click the "Add to source control" at the bottom right, it always tries to create the repo in D:. Which only works for the first project - after that, it fails because there's already a repo there. How do I create my repos on the C: drive with file names or directories that reflect the project name?